# Android 5.0.1 VerifyError?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, verifyerror

I have just updated the OS on my phone to Android 5.0.1.   Since this update, an app that I am working on, that is working perfectly fine on my other devices, is now throwing an error in 5.0.1 only.  I have no idea what this error means, and it isn't pointing me to a suspicious line of code like it often does.

Has anyone seen this or know what it is about with the new 5.0.1?

```
06-23 16:52:37.840  10976-10976/rule02.touchpool E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: rule02.touchpool, PID: 10976
java.lang.VerifyError: rule02.touchpool.GameScreen
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1650)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2537)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2759)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:178)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having any issues since the Android update, I have found and resolved my issue.

The allowed maximum method size has obviously changed.  Some of my methods were quite large and complex, and this new limit was obviously exceeded.

This fix was to break larger sections of code into smaller sections.

Hope this helps someone.